# 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation' while calling SocialDataService.asmx

Tags: development, web-services, social-tag

I am calling methods of the SharePoint webservice - Lists.asmx and SocialDataService.asmx via a C# application.

While calling methods of the Lists.asmx works perfectly fine, methods of the SocialDataService.asmx on the same list/list items fail with a SoapException with the message Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Is there something specific I need to do in terms of permissions in order to call methods on SocialDataService.asmx ?

Here is a test I have to try and obtain the tags for a specified document -

```
 var client = new Tests.SharePointSocialDataWebService.SocialDataService();
 client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
 client.Url = TestWebSiteURL + "/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx";
 var tags = client.GetTags("http:sp/sites/sitecollection/website/DocumentLibrary/test.bin");
```

Comment: What were you trying to do? Some code would help, or at least let us know what socialdataservice operation you are trying to invoke.

Comment: @PirateEric - Thanks for the reply. I've added some test code.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call `GetTags` method from `SocialDataService` service the user should have rights to manage User Profile service application as shown below (All Rights)

[image]

otherwise you will get `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception

---

For managing User Profile service application go to Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Service Application -> User Profile service application -> Administrators button in Ribbon UI

Comment: cant somehow see this page. After I click on 'User Profile Service Application', I see no Ribbon UI (and hence no 'Administrators' button)

Comment: Do not click on the text of 'User Profile Service Application', click on the space after 'User Profile Service Application' instead, then the ribbon will show.

Answer (score 0):

Important to note that whatever account you use to call the web service, it must also have access to the site through which you call the service. In alwayslearning's question, that was represented by "TestWebSiteUrl".